# In what language is media players in websites written

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

So videos is used a lot in websites
you can put a video into your website using this html code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But the media player that will appear is different from the media player in youtube.com (for example)
My question is how do i write a media player for my website?

Comment: this html5. video player in youtube is flash but you can switch to html5 in youtube as well

Comment: if you want to customize html5 video player here is a tutorial http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: if you use flash you need to embed the flash player in html aswell aslo your embedded player you would make in flash for appearance and controls

Comment: HTML, JavaScript, CSS, Flash ActionScript

Answer (score 2):

The native controls vary from browser to browser. YouTube does not use the native controls, it uses a custom set of controls that tell the video to do things like play, pause, set volume etc..

Answer (score 0):

Sites like Youtube use Flash. The ones built into the browsers (non-Flash) are likely C or C++. Maybe some Objective C in Safari.